# Drupal 7 rendered form error messages not displaying after submitting form twice

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

In Drupal 7, I have created a custom template for user register page.

The template name is `page--user--register.tpl.php`.

We have managed to create the required look and feel.

Everything is working fine except the following:

1) After user submits invalid form, it shows error messages.

2) User again submit the form and the error messages are not getting displayed.

3) Though the invalid fields are being highlighted.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Downvoter, please explain why downvoted?

Comment: Downvoter, please explain why downvoted? I have tried first, then asked question. Also, I have described my problem very well. Whats wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drupal all error message are print from page.tpl.php using $messages template variable, and for you questions it seems it is available, are you using any ajax kind behavior for your form?